# Is it possible to create Multiple CSS3 using Transform or gradient Background?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this kind of Layout using Css Transform or gradient Background?(see image below). Right now im stuck with it using conic-gradient, i dont know how to put a gradient background on it.

[image]

see snippet below. run the code snippet as fullpage.

Thanks Guys.

```css
//gol-bg
.my-bg-image {
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=Background-image+Backgground-image+Background-image") 0 0 / cover no-repeat;
}
.gol-bg {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 700px;
  position: relative;
  background: conic-gradient(
     transparent 136deg, transparent 0 140deg, yellow 140deg);
  .my-content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bg-dark my-bg-image">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="gol-bg">
        <div class="my-content">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/. You can select a shape on the right side or create one. Then you can take the `clip-path` code at the bottom

Comment: yup i already tried it..thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understood your question correctly but

Yes, you can use multiple transforms

(Also, take a look at this:
https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Here's an example:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5em auto; /* Just to center it a bit */
  
/* Transform part */
  transform: scale(2) rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div>Hello World</div>
```

Comment: description and code have been updated but i dont know how to put gradient background on it. thx

Answer (score 1):

this may not be the answer you are looking for but you can do this too. CSS is capable of making all sorts of shapes.

```css
   .my-bg-image {
         background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/728x90.png?text=Background-image+Backgground-image+Background-image") 0 0 / cover no-repeat;
    }
     .gol-bg {
         display: block;
         position: relative;
         width: 250px;
         height: 0px;
         border-left: 50px solid red;
         border-right: 50px solid red;
         border-bottom: 100px solid red;
         border-top: 100px solid red;
         position: relative;
      }
     .gol-bg:after {
         content: '';
         position: absolute;
         background: transparent linear-gradient(91deg, #02b3bc 0, #171c8f 100%) 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;
          width: 0;
          height: 0;
          border-left: 250px solid transparent;
          border-right: 100px solid transparent;
          border-bottom: 100px solid red;
          position: absolute;
          content: "";
          top: 0px;
          left: -50px;
    }
     .gol-bg .my-content {
         position: relative;
         z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="bg-dark my-bg-image">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="gol-bg">
        <div class="my-content">content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: description and code have been updated but i dont know how to put gradient background on it. thx